# Как определить есть ли фрагмент на активности

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Начал работать с фрагментами, создал NavigationBar, при выборе определенных пунктов подгружаются фрагменты, при нажатии кнопок на фрагментах кидает на новую активность. На эмуляторах, и вообще на всех физических устройствах знакомых и всех которые я нашел все работает, но на моем Meizu M2 mini при возвращении с активности обратно в меню с фрагментами, ранее подгруженный фрагмент не удаляется.
В приложении я определял наличие фрагментов через теги.

Вопрос как можно проверить есть ли какие-либо фрагменты на активности ? И с чем вообще может быть связано такое поведение ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить можно так:

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

Comment: т.е. мы ищем есть ли какой либо тег в контейнере, если есть вернет true, иначе false соответственно ?

Comment: Нет, эта штука возвращает фрагмент который показан в контейнере, а тэг это просто метод у фрагмента. Добавил код на java.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращает количество записей  стека в настоящее время:

```
getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
```